# How to find a document based on the embedded object key value?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose .findOne() how would you find a document based on the key value that is deep into the object? Like for example how would I find a document based on the meta.votes value?

```
 var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String, // String is shorthand for {type: String}
    author: String,
    body:   String,
    comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    hidden: Boolean,
    meta: {
      votes: Number,
      favs:  Number
    }
  });
```